# Pronunciation of 'damning' with /n/

Tags: pronunciation, inflections

The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary and [OED](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00057363) accept /n/ as a secondary pronunciation /ˈdæm**n**ɪŋ/ for the form *damning* (unlike for, say, *condemning*).

Is the latter used for the adjective, similarly to the appearance of /n/ in say *damnable*?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul compare https://www.oed.com/oed2/00057363 and https://www.oed.com/oed2/00057362

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Also:  _damned, ppl. a. (dæmd, poet. ˈ**dæmnɪd**)_  [f. damn v. + -ed1.]  https://www.oed.com/oed2/00057355

Comment: It's strange. I've never heard [ˈdæmnɪd] either.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul more info.: https://www.oed.com/oed2/00072077

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul neither  in **condemning** https://www.oed.com/oed2/00046570 or **condemned** https://www.oed.com/oed2/00046566

Comment: See also https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/damning-adjective-%CB%88d%C3%A6mn%C9%AA%C5%8B.3749953/#post-19144116

Comment: @Greybeard Check also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Tea_room/2020/October#damning_adjective_/%CB%88d%C3%A6mn%C9%AA%C5%8B/

Comment: A spelling pronunciation if ever there was one.

Comment: *"The cluster <- mn> in word- final position appears only in non- native words: autumn, column, condemn, damn, solemn. In some instances of early borrowings, the <- mn> was avoided from the start, thus Lat. hymnus, Late Lat. ymnus, OE epenthetic ymen; in damnthe input was Old French dampn- er~ damn- er, the ME adopted forms are predominantly with <- mpn- >, but <dam(e)> is already in evidence c. 1440; note also the spelling <dambd> for ‘damned’ (1611).* ...... (cont.)

Comment: .... *The phonetic nature of this 
simplification is based on avoidance of similarity: the cluster [- mn] is 
perceptually opaque because of the overlapping features of the two 
adjacent nasals. As in the case of /- mb/- simplifi cation, morphological 
composition may affect the realisation: damner, damninghave no [- n- ], 
but damnation(1300), damnable(1303) preserve it; hymner‘a singer of 
hymns’ is both [himə(r)] ~ [himnə(r)], but hymnalhas [- n- ].* .... (cont.)

Comment: .... *We preserve  [- m.n- ]  in alumnus, alumna, but not in the shortened form alum
(1683). The realisation of [- n] requires a vowel- initial suffi x, but it is not 
suffi cient: (rare) autumny, no [- n- ], unlike autumnal, solemnity, where [- n- ] 
is resyllabifi ed in the syllable onset*" 
....................................
From *A Historical Phonology of English* by Donka Minkova.

Answer (score 6):

The *n* in words like *damn, condemn, solemn, autumn* is silent because the cluster /-mn/ violates the Phonotactic rules of English. [Phonotactic rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/548361/365490) are language-specific rules that determine the permissible sound sequences in a particular language. According to English Phonotactics, 'two nasals cannot occur next to each other within the same syllable'. Donka Minkova says 'the cluster [-mn] is perceptually opaque because of the overlapping features of the two adjacent nasals'. <sup>[[A Historical Phonology of English](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Historical_Phonology_of_English.html?id=uGs3BQAAQBAJ)]</sup>

According to [*A History of Modern English Sounds and Morphology* by Eilert Ekwall](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_History_of_Modern_English_Sounds_and_M.html?id=4-46swEACAAJ&redir_esc=y), the loss of *n* after *m* is attested from the 16th century. Eilert goes on to say that the [n] was lost regularly in final position and before consonant (e.g. *solemnly*). [Dobson](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=YLm0AAAAIAAJ) says that the loss of [n] can be attributed to the loss of final *e* ([ə]).

Almost all these words that end with *-mn* came from French and had a final [ə] after the *-mn-*, so the [n] must have been pronounced because there was a vowel after the *-mn-* which would split up the cluster /mn/.

In some cases, the /n/ gets pronounced when a vowel-initial suffix (such as *-able, -ation, or *-er*)
follows the ‹mn›, where the [n] is resyllabified as the onset of the next syllable, though the pattern is very irregular. *Damnable* is pronounced [ˈdæ**m**.**n**əbl̩] — the vowel in ‑*able* splits
up the cluster /mn/. The same thing happens in *damnation, solemnity, autumnal, condemnation, hymnal* etc (I.e. the /n/ is resyllabified as the onset of the next syllable).

The /n/ doesn't get surface in inflectional words such as *damning, damned, hymning, hymned, condemning, condemned* etc. Eilert says that they're influenced by  *damn, hymn, condemn*.

*Damning* is not pronounced with an /n/ in Modern English. William Henry in [*How Should I Pronounce? Or, The Principles of the Art of Correct Pronunciation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sn5IAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA217&dq=%22damning%22%20pronunciation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM9PWJjeXuAhVIi1wKHeReB204ChDoATAAegQIABAC#v=onepage&q=%22damning%22&f=false) says that 'damning' is not pronounced with an /n/:

> > [image: daming, not damning]

However, some sources claim that the pronunciation with an /n/ has existed. [*A Practical Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5YVDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA94&dq=%22damning%22%20pronunciation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL3q3l4uTuAhWPfMAKHdzbB7QQ6AEwB3oECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22damning%22%20pronunciation&f=false) by Noah Webster does list the pronunciation with /n/:

> > [image: 'damning']

John Walker in his [*Critical Pronouncing Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Critical_Pronouncing_Dictionary_and_Ex.html?id=LeOD_sYogbsC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=damned&f=false) also lists a second disyllabic pronunciation for *damned*, where the /n/ gets pronounced:

> > [image: damned pronunciation]

Also from [*Fowler's Modern English Usage*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_New_Fowler_s_Modern_English_Usage.html?id=sG8YAAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) (p195):

> damn. In all uses as n., adj., v., and adv. the n is silent; also in the oblique forms ***damned* (but often disyllabic in verse)**, damning. The n is sounded in *damnable, damnation, damnatory, damnification*, and *damnify*.

About *limn*, Fowler says (p461):

> ... the base-form is, like *solemn*, pronounced with the *n* silent. The inflected forms are *limns* /lɪmz/, *limned* /lɪmd/, ***limner* /ˈlɪmnə/** and *limning* /ˈlɪmɪŋ/ or **/ˈlɪmnɪŋ/**.

The *-ed* endings were [pronounced](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/553763/365490) with a separate syllable back in Middle English, so *banned* would've been pronounced with two syllables. In Early Modern English, however, the unstressed vowel in the suffix *-ed* was lost (except after /t/ and /d/). So after a voiced sound, the *-ed* became /d/ and after voiceless sounds, it became /t/.

In most adjectives such as *wicked, naked, blessed, crooked* etc., the vowel remained, so the *-ed* is still pronounced as a separate syllable in those words. I assume *damned* followed the same sequence at some point, that's why John Walker lists the disyllabic pronunciation. In Modern English, however, both *damning* (v & adj) and *damned* (v & adj) are pronounced without the /n/. Or the adjectives lost their /n/'s due to analogy with *damn* which had no /n/.

From [*Modern English Grammar on Historical
Principles* (7 vols.). 1–7 (1949)](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Modern_English_Grammar_on_Historical_P.html?id=0CYIsm4MaIkC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) by Otto Jespersen.

> ### Loss of final /n/
>
> After /m/, a final /n/ has been lost (assimilated to /m/): damn
> /damn/ now [dæm], condemn, hymn, limn, column, solemn, autumn. The
> loss is shown by such inverse spellings as *solembe*,
> (Sh LL V. 2.118, quarto of 1598); C 1627 expressly says that *n* is mute in
> *solemne* and *hymne*. *N* has been everywhere retained in spelling,
> except in occasional *dam* (for *damned*?: Meredith EH 134 “and dam
> rum chaps they were!”).
>
> Homonyms: damn = dam, hymn = him, limn = limb formerly lim.
>
> **Before a vowel, /n/ is retained: *damnation, condemnation,
> damnable, autumnal, solemnity.* Before *‑ing* /n/ was formerly heard
> in “the solemn articulation of *damning, condemning* etc.” (E 1766,
> also Walker); now the pronunciation without [n] has been analogously
> extended to these forms, though the NED has both pronunciations for
> the participle (but not the verbal noun) *damning* and recognizes
> [ˈdæmnɪd] as a poetical form of *damned* by the side of [dæmd]**.

I think the shift from *amn’t* to *ain’t* is also relevant. The contraction
of *am not* **used** to be *amn’t*, where we see the same cluster /mn/, but it
got reduced to /n/. Here it’s /n/ and not /m/ because of the following /t/, and also per *Phonotactics* because:

> a nasal following an obstruent in the coda should be homorganic (having the same place of articulation) with the obstruent.