# Why did the F of "sneeze" and "snore" change to an S in English history?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, historical-change, old-english, middle-english

The etymologies of "sneeze" and "snore" suggest that they were once pronounced with **/f/**. Here is what [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sneeze) (from which all the following information also comes) says:

- From Middle English **snesen** (“to sneeze”), alteration of earlier **fnesen** (“to sneeze”), from Old English **fnēosan** (“to snort, sneeze”)

In [Old English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fneosan#Old_English), it was **fnēosan** and Wiktionary also lists its pronunciation: **/ˈfne͜oː.sɑn/, [ˈfne͜oː.zɑn]** which also has **/f/**.

In [Middle English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snesen#Middle_English), it was **/ˈsneːzən/**. Something happened in between Old and Middle English that changed the /f/ to /s/.

#### Snore

- "[snore](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snore)": [Old English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fnora#Old_English) **fnora** and pronunciation was: **/ˈfno.rɑ/**.

Was there a change from **/f/** to **/s/**? Why did the /f/ change to /s/? I mean, there are a lot of sound changes in the history of English but this is kind of unusual.

Comment: fn is more unwieldy than sn. It takes more articulatory effort. I don't do historical linguistics, but things tend to evolve toward what is simpler to say, I'd warrant.

Comment: Fnore is quite onomatopœic though, I rather like it! (In BrE anyway. Unless AmE speakers also snore in AmE..!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Edwin Ashworth's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/551434/365490) is basically right, but I'm going to shed some light on its linguistics.

Every language has a unique set of rules that govern the permissible sequences of sounds (which sounds are allowed to make a [consonant cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_cluster) i.e. licit and illicit sequences of sounds). A sequence that is possible in one language may not be allowed in another, for instance, the cluster [pn-] is allowed in Greek, but not in English therefore the ‹p› in the word *pneumonia* is silent in English, but pronounced in Greek. These specific rules are called *[phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics)*.

In simple words, phonotactics studies *what sounds go together, and where can they be found*. I have explained English Phonotactics in [an answer to your previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/548361/365490).

Over time, a language may undergo phonotactic variation and change. For example, the letter K in the word *know* wasn't silent until [Modern English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know) (it was pronounced in [Middle English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knowen#Middle_English) and [Old English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cnawan#Old_English)). The letter K went silent probably because it was awkward for Modern English speakers to pronounce a [nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_consonant) (/m n ŋ/) right after a [plosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plosive) (/p t k b d g/) in the same syllable. The plosive is therefore silent in words like *pneumonia, know, gnome* etc.

The tautosyllabic cluster (within the same syllable) /fn-/ is ill-formed in Modern English. The same thing might have happened to it. It might have become 'awkward to pronounce' and English speakers either dropped the /f/ or changed it to /s/.

According to [*The Cambridge Handbook of English Historical Linguistics* by Merja Kytö, Päivi Pahta](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Cambridge_Handbook_of_English_Histor.html?id=NrkaDAAAQBAJ):

> Historical changes in phonotactics are documented for English. For instance, the sequence /fn-/ was found in Old English in words like ***fn**ēosan* ‘sneeze; gasp’, ***fn**ær(ett)an* ‘snore’ (Lutz 1991: 234) but was later lost either by a shift of /f-/ to /s-/ or due to replacement by another word, e.g. *fnēosan* ‘gasp’→Old Norse *gasp* or Anglo-Norman *pant*(Lutz 1991: 236).

Though it doesn't explain why the /f/ became /s/.

Also from [Duisburg-Essen's website](https://www.uni-due.de/SHE/SHE_Phonology.htm):

> The set of permissible combinations has varied over the history of English, either by elements being lost, cf. /x/ and /ɣ/ above, or by the simplification or alteration of cluster types. In Old English /h/ and /w/ could occur before /r/ and /l/ as in *hlaf* /hl-/ ‘loaf’ or *writan* /wr-/ ‘write’; /h/ could also occur before /n/ as in *hnutu* /hn-/ ‘nut’ Such clusters were simplified during Middle English and only the second element of each cluster prevailed. **Initial clusters like /fn-/ in *fneosan* ‘sneeze’ were changed to /sn-/.** The combinations /gn-/ and /kn-/, as in *gnagan* ‘gnaw’ and *cnēo* ‘knee’ respectively, seem to have survived well into the Middle English period.

According to [*Phonotactics of consonant clusters in the history of English* by Katarzyna Dziubalska-Kołaczyk](https://repozytorium.amu.edu.pl/bitstream/10593/10000/1/WA_Dziubalska-Ko%C5%82aczyk_Phonotactics%20of%20consonant%20clusters%20in%20the%20history%20of%20English.pdf), /fn-/ lost the /f/ and was replaced by /s/ in some words e.g. *fnēosan > sneeze*.

She further says:

> Apart from being replaced by /sn-/, /fn-/ also changed into /g-/, e.g. *fnasten* > *gasp*.
> [...]
> /fn-/ → /n-/ (→/sn-/)

And,

> "*Fricative* + *nasal*" belongs to the medial cluster space, so the change from /fn-/ to /sn-/ does not essentially improve the cluster, although /s/ is stronger than /f/ and as such improves the perceptual distance between C1 and C2. The change to a single consonant is a change to CV.

Another interesting explanation of  /f/ to /s/ shift can be found in [*For the Love of Language: An Introduction to Linguistics* by Kate Burridge, Tonya N. Stebbins](https://books.google.com/books?id=LFi2CgAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (p136). They propose the idea of *[phonaesthemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme)*. They claim that the change from /fn-/ to /sn-/ is because there weren't many *fn-* words left in English* and there were so many words with the phonaestheme *sn-*. [The phonaestheme ***sn-*** is often found in words dealing with the nose:](https://www.thoughtco.com/phonestheme-word-sounds-1691505) *snore, snorkel, sniff, sniffle, snuffle, snuff, snivel, snout, snoot, snub, snot, snob, snotty, sneer, sneeze, snoop*. The fact that so many *sn-* words had something to do with 'nose' eliminated *fn-* and made *sneeze* a natural fit.

* <sup>Both **fnast* and **fnese* are also labelled 'obsolete' in the OED [[Consonant Change in English Worldwide](https://books.google.com/books/about/Consonant_Change_in_English_Worldwide.html?id=1ip9DAAAQBAJ)]</sup>

---

Now there's a concept of *Minimal Sonority Distance* for onset clusters. I have explained sonority in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/548361/365490).

**Minimal Sonority Distance:**
Sounds of a language are divided into several degrees on a scale according to their [sonority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonority_hierarchy). In English, four degrees have been proposed for [glides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) and other consonants.

**Sonority scale of English consonants and glides:**

- Glides [j w] -> 4
- Liquids [l ɹ] -> 3
- Nasals [m n] -> 2
- Obstruents [f t k] -> 1

There is a requirement on the Minimal Sonority Distance (MSD) between the two sounds in an onset cluster. In English the MSD is assumed to be 2 i.e. the sonority of the second sound must be at least two degrees higher than that of the first.

For instance, the sonority of [n] is 2 and that of [f] is 1 -> **2 - 1 = 1** while the required MSD is **2**, so the cluster [fn-] is ill-formed and no Modern English word starts with [fn-].

Now for the cluster [fl-] (as in *fly*): the sonority of [l] is 3 and that of [f] is 1 -> **3 - 1 = 2**, it conforms to MSD, therefore the cluster [fl-] is well-formed.

[sn-] is an exception to MSD. [Here's](http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/002755/current.pdf) a whole paper on the unusual behaviour of /s/.

<sup>[Simplified from [Two Theories of Onset Clusters by San Duanmu](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237229428_Two_Theories_of_Onset_Clusters)]</sup>

There are many other exceptions, however. (See [Two Theories of Onset Clusters by San Duanmu](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237229428_Two_Theories_of_Onset_Clusters) for exceptions and their solutions).

Comment: I’m curious about the purported derivation of _gasp_ from Middle English _fnasten_. As I’ve understood it (and as listed in the Wiktipnary entry for [_gasp_](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/gasp)), the Middle English was replaced by a Norse-derived term, compare Icelandic [_geispa_](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/geispa).

Comment: Your MSD theory is wrong about [sn-], isn't it? Which is a shame, because [sn-] is precisely what you are trying to explain.

Comment: @TonyK: [sn-] violates MSD (it's an exception, as always). Clusters with /s/ often violate phonological processes, for example, clusters of /s/ and plosives violate Sonority Sequencing Principle.

Comment: "an initial [s], and sometimes [ʃ], is allowed to precede almost any consonant, regardless of the sonority distance or places of articulation.For example, [st-] is good even though the MSD is 0." [Two Theories of Onset Clusters]

Answer (score 8):

[Word Histories](https://wordhistories.net/2017/06/02/origin-of-sneeze/) contains:

> The verb fnese having gone out of use early in the 15th century, its
> place was mainly supplied by neeze, meaning to sneeze, first recorded
> around 1325. The adoption of sneeze was probably assisted by its
> phonetic appropriateness, that is to say, it may have been felt as a
> strengthened form of neeze. ... Neese/neeze is still found in Scotland, Northern
> Ireland, and Northern England. [adapted]

This seems to imply a movement involving first an eliding of the awkward f, and a later addition of the s in line with say *snore*. Apparently, AHD 3rd edition espouses this etymology.

.......

But Word Histories also contains:

> The verb *sneeze* is an alteration of fnese due to misreading or
> misprinting it as ſnese (= snese) after the initial consonant cluster
> fn- had become unfamiliar.
>
> For instance, in William Caxton’s 1483 edition of The festyuall, by
> the Augustinian canon regular John Mirk (floruit late 14th-early 15th
> centuries), the spelling is fnese, whereas it is snese in the 1508
> edition by Wynkyn de Worde (here, the verb means to snort)....

This implies a single-step switch in pronunciation. A mumpsimus ... but an explanation AHD3 considers a folk etymology.

Comment: You're quite right. It's basically because of English Phonotactics Constraints; the cluster /fn-/ is forbidden. Have a look at  [*The Cambridge Handbook of English Historical Linguistics* by Merja Kytö, Päivi Pahta]: *"Historical changes in phonotactics are documented for English. For
instance, the sequence /fn-/ was found in Old English in words like 'fnēosan'
‘sneeze; gasp’, 'fnær(ett)an' "snore" (Lutz 1991: 234) but was later lost either
by a shift of /f-/ to /s-/ or due to replacement by another word, e.g.'fnēosan'
‘gasp’→Old Norse 'gasp' or Anglo-Norman 'pant' (Lutz 1991: 236)"*

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Also in *fnast* < Old English *fnǽst* strong masculine, < root of Old Norse *fnasa, fnása* to snort, breathe hard.  During the OE/ON contact period, such borrowings were common because Old Norse — and ancestral Proto-Germanic in general — very much allowed tautosyllabic /fn/ clusters at the onset, something which is no longer permissible in Modern English.

Comment: This might be half true. In Dutch, *to sneeze* is *niezen*. *sneeze* and *neeze* may have competed for a while.

Comment: When two opposing views are posted, 'This might be half true' isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The OED gives

> **sneeze (v.)**
>
> **Etymology:** apparently an alteration of fnese v., due to misreading or misprinting it as ‘**ſ**nese’, *[edit: **ſ** = the "long" letter 's']* after the initial combination **f**n- had become unfamiliar.
>
> Fnese had apparently gone out of use early in the 15th cent., its place being mainly supplied by nese neeze v. The adoption of sneeze was probably assisted by its phonetic appropriateness; it may have been felt as a strengthened form of neeze.
>
> In the following places where sn- is printed in modern editions the correct reading is fn-: Trevisa Higden (Rolls) V. 389; [etc.]

1495   Trevisa's Bartholomeus De Proprietatibus Rerum (de Worde) xvii. xxxviii. 625   Yf it [sc. cummin] is..blowen in to the nosethrilles,..it makith a man snese [Bodl. MS. fnese].

Interestingly, the OED does not give the same etymology for "snore", which, according to it, seems to always have been "snore".

The [Old English Translator](https://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/index.htm) gives

> **fnora** (n.) weak **1. a sneeze 2. sneezing**

Answer (score -5):

It was still pronounced as 's', but 's' used to be written down as 'f'.

Similar to when you see 'ye olde' - a 'y' was pronounced as what we now write as 'th'.

So it was a written change rather than a sound change.

Comment: No. You're confusing the 'long s' with a true f. There really was an f in fnesen. Probably others confusing f and long s [[Logophilus](https://logophilius.blogspot.com/2020/02/lets-talk-about-lex.html?m=1)] brought about this mumpsimus. Complete with change in pronunciation.

Comment: There were many apparent spelling issues with the long s and thorn letters, but this doesn’t seem related.

Comment: F and S are two different letters, and anyone who can read older English writing or print would have been able to tell them apart, as F has a cross bar and long S doesn’t. This doesn’t explain why Chaucer (for example) would write “He slepeth, and he fnorteth”, one word with S, one word with F. (If you look elsewhere, you will be able to find that he also wrote words such as “snowes” with an S.)

Comment: The word fnesen was spelled fnesen not ſnesen.

Comment: Now I am getting confused.  Is this a situation in which we are discussing the symbol or the sound?  

Is it like the Welsh "dd" that sounds like "th" ( or the satanically inspired welsh "ll" that sounds like you spat on the floor..) that "look" like familiar english letters, but the latin alphabet has really just been used as symbols for something else entirely. Like the russian cccp that really did sound like sssr.

Or is it a case of the sound "f" as used in "frog" "friend" and "fun" has over time become an "s" as in "snake", "soup" and "suffer"?

Comment: Are you saying that the evidence provided by Edwin Ashworth and Decapitated Soul in support of the pronunciation with /f/ is wrong? And the pronunciations recorded in Wikitionary are also incorrect? Can you back your answer up with some evidence please?