# Why is "loosely" divided into syllables as "LOOS-LEE" and not "LOO-SLEE"?

Tags: syllables

About ten days ago [I had asked a question about "syllabification"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558942/how-to-syllabify-obsessive-ob-se-siv-or-ob-ses-iv) and received an excellent answer. That answer said: "*there's a phonological rule called Maximal Onset Principle (MOP), according to which intervocalic consonants should be syllabified as the onset of the following syllable as long as the Phonotactic constraints allow it. This would mean that VCV has to be syllabified as V.CV as long as the onset of the second syllable is permissible*."

And that's why "banana" (in British English) should be divided as /bə.ˈnɑː.nə/ and in American English as  /bə.ˈnæn.ə/.

It took me a week to fully understand the theories explained in that answer. Now if I understand it correctly, the word "loosely", /ˈluːsli/, should be divided as **/ˈluː.sli/**. That is, the *sl* should be the "onset" of the following syllable (compare /bə.ˈnɑː.nə/), But it is divided as /ˈluːs.li/ instead.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loosely) is quite consistent with their syllabification and it gives /ˈluːs.li/.

Is it because "loosely" is made up of "loose" and "ly" and should be divided as separately? Or is it an exception?

Thanks!

Comment: The only difference I hear between BE and AE banana is the central 'a'. Merriam-Webster shows  bə-ˈ**na**-nə.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Yes, and because of that pesky vowel, 'banana' is syllabified differently in BrE and AmE.

Comment: The problem with syllabification in English is that, while syllabic peaks are clear, their boundaries are not, and fas pea trules tend to blur them even more. Syllables do not necessarily begin between phonemes, for instance.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615072/2085).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you're dividing into syllables, morpheme boundaries often overrule the maximal onset principle. In fact, you can tell that the /s/ belongs to the first syllable because the vowel in *loosely* is shorter than that in *loser*, and vowels in syllables that end with a voiceless consonant are shortened in English.

This doesn't always happen. In the word *waitress*, the root word is obviously *wait*, so you might expect the syllable division to be after the /t/. But the pronunciation in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/waitress) is  /ˈweɪ.trəs/, showing that in this case Maximum Onset Principle has overruled the morpheme boundaries.

Comment: I'm sceptical about the claim that 'there's a shorter vowel in the first syllable (syllables ending with voiceless consonants are shortened in English)'. I don't think it's because of that. See for instance [**rooster**](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/rooster), which is syllabified as **/ˈruː.stə** (AmE: /ˈruː.stɚ/), not /ˈruːs.tə/. If it's because of the short vowel, then why isn't *rooster* syllabified as /ˈruːs.tə/?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: I think you're right (after looking at *data* and *daytime*); the *Cambridge Dictionary* isn't taking vowel length into account when syllabifying, just morpheme boundaries. I'm disappointed.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I think you're going deaf! Just tried it with four native speakers, who didn't know why they were being asked. All agreed the /u:/ is *rooster* was longer when their recordings were played back. I can here it too! In fact you can hear it just with *roost* and *rooster*!

Comment: @Araucaria: But what about *data* and *daytime*?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: What about 'precisely' (/prɪˈsaɪs.li/)? Shouldn't it be syllabified as /prɪˈsaɪ.sli/? (Am I misunderstanding something here?)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Why'd it be .sli ?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: According to MOP, it should be /prɪˈsaɪ.sli/  which it isn't. I think Peter Shor is right that morpheme boundaries override MOP at times.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I agree with John Wells and PS. The phonetic data to me seem to say that the /s/ in *rooster* is in the second syllable, because the first syllable doesn't seem to be clipped. But I don't believe this has anything to do with the MOP.

Comment: @PeterShor Wow, they have the /t/ in the second syllable in *data*! I hadn't looked! That's definitely weird. If it's flapped, it's got to be in the syllable coda! Well I never, as we say over here sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

The Maximal Onset Principle is a common idea about how syllabification should work, but in many contexts, there isn’t much evidence that it is how syllabification really works.

In fact, it’s difficult to get evidence for syllabification in general. Aside from native speaker intuition, which does not always agree, the indirect evidence used to argue for syllable division can often be interpreted in ways that don’t require reference to the concept of the syllable. Some linguists are skeptical or agnostic about the linguistic reality of syllable division.

In English, specifically, the Maximal Onset Principle seems to fail in two ways that are relevant to “loosely”:

1. Morphological division. As Peter Shor mentioned, syllable boundaries seem to coincide in some, but not all cases with morpheme boundaries, like the boundary between the base *loose* and the suffix *-ly.*
2. Stress attraction. While not accepted by all phonologists, there is a notable theory that consonants and consonant clusters in English are preferentially syllabified with stressed syllables (with some phonotactic restrictions), even when occurring between vowels. One of the most notable articulators of this theory is John Wells. In Wells’ theory of syllabification, *loose.ly,* *waitr.ess,* and *self.ish* are syllabified based on this phonological criterion; in contrast, words like *shell.fish* are syllabified based on morphology according to Wells (“[Syllabification and allophony](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/syllabif.htm)", 1990).

Comment: '*wai**tr**.ess,*'?!

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: Yes! See the linked page untder “The affricate condition”

Comment: +1 And in addition there are allophones that only occur in syllable onsets or syllable codas that can tell us where a particular phoneme seems to be. There is also the prefortis clipping of vowels and other sonorants. (All of which is in Wells' paper)