# How to syllabify "very" or "merry" etc in British English?

Tags: british-english, syllables

How should words like *merry or very* be syllabified in British English. I learned from the [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558942/how-to-syllabify-obsessive-ob-se-siv-or-ob-ses-iv) to my first question that words that have vowels like /ʌ ɪ ʊ ɛ/ should have a consonant after that vowel. So "obsessive" is /əb.sɛs.sɪv/ (the middle syllable has a consonant after the vowel ɛ).

Below is the paragraph from that answer: Yet another theory says that the consonant following the lax vowels /ʌ ɪ ʊ ɛ/ should be ambisyllabic. 'Ambisyllabic' means that it it belongs to both the preceding and the following syllable. So according to the ambisyllabicity theory, obsessive can be syllabified as:

/əb.sɛs.sɪv/

--

But what if there is an **r** after the vowel **ɛ** in words like "merry" and "very"?

If I divide "very" into syllables as **vɛr.i** (because the vowel **ɛ** should have a consonant after it) then the first syllables ends in an **r** and in British English, words do not end in **R sound** (for example the R in "bar" is silent).

What should I do in the case I described above? How should one syllabify?

..........

"**Closed**. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."

It is strange that this question was closed. I have provided details in my question. Could you please tell me **how else** can I clarify it?

Is there really no way to do the division of those words? Please consider reopening my question; I really am confused as to how to do the division of those words. Thank you so much.

---

Why would you need to know this?  For example, for writing music for singers:

> [image: music]

> [image: more music]

Comment: It's highly controversial. How else would you syllabify 'very' if you can't syllabify it as /ˈvɛ.ri/ or /ˈvɛr.i/? I don't think this question is answerable. ([Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/very) syllabifies 'very' as /ˈver.i/ for BrE.)

Comment: This idea that British words (in non-rhotic Southern English dialects) never end in an r seems dubious, as non-rhotic English dialects use a linking r at the end of a word when it's followed by another vowel. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R If you think there's an r, transcribe it. (But remember that syllabification isn't a simple thing and there are a lot of disputes.)

Comment: @StuartF Those r's are pronounced because there are vowels after them. My question is completely different from what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Guest1 you're talking about a situation where you have an "r" followed by a vowel. Everything I've seen suggests a linking "r" is pronounced similarly to a normal "r". Regardless, I agree with Decapitated Soul's comment.

Comment: @Guest1: You say "Those r's are pronounced because there are vowels after them" ... so would you syllabify the "the idea of" with an intrusive /r/ as /ðiː.aɪˈdɪə.rəv/? Bur *rov* is not a word.

Comment: @PeterShor: That's exactly how *I* would syllabify *the idea of*. I don't understand why you say ‘.. *rov* is not a word’. Why does it need to be a word?

Comment: The syllables in British and American English are the same thing for these. You are not using this term correctly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification

Comment: @Lambie Ohhhh.. my bad. thanks. its clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In British English, you can syllabify them as /vɛr.i/ and /mɛr.i/ i.e. the r belongs to the previous syllable. For reference, you can see John Wells' syllabification (as he has done in Longman Pronunciation Dictionary) and Peter Roach's (Cambridge Online Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

*er* is a R-controlled syllable, so the *r* is needed to complete the R-Controlled vowel team **-er**. *y* stands alone because the *y* is a vowel in this word.
It is acceptable to have a syllable with 1 vowel only, but not acceptable to have a syllable with 1 consonant only.